# Scripts load as default document, but not when referenced directly

Tags: windows, iis-7, coldfusion, windows-server-2008, coldfusion-10

Just fired up a fresh Windows Server 2008 instance on Amazon EC2 to begin messing around with the ColdFusion 10 beta and ran into an interesting issue.

This WORKS and properly renders the default index.cfm in the root:
mydomain.com/

This however DOES NOT work:
mydomain.com/index.cfm

Any .cfm file referenced directly within the url doesn't load but if referenced as the default document in a given directory does work.

Like I said, this is a fresh install with nothing outside of the ColdFusion 10 public beta installed along side IIS 7.  Ideas?

Comment: Now that CF10 is using Tomcat, I would look there.  Check and see what your servlet-mapping values are within web.xml - make sure there is a value for `<url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a connector issue from within IIS. The IIS CFM Handler Mappings *should have* been taken care of during the installation process but apparently that didn't happen in this case. It's possible IIS is missing a feature (like ISAPI support) that the connector needs in order to function.

You can try re-installing (and thus re-running the connection process) or you may be able to use wsconfig directly to re-install *just* the connector bit:

ColdFusion10\config\wsconfig

... whatever is easiest for you.

Comment: If the ISAPI configuration is wrong, then how could the default document work? That gets passed through IIS too....

Comment: Ran the web server config tool, deleted the existing web server that the CF10 installer created and then added it again.  That seemed to do the trick!  Thanks Jordan!

Comment: Jake - I agree with you. If the handlers for .cfm were not working then how could it serve up index.cfm?  except perhaps it served it up without *executing* it eh? ... as text/html?  In either case looks like Dan marked the connector fix as the correct one... perhaps just running it replaced the handlers and shored up whatever was wrong.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Default documents can be handled separately from mapped files in IIS. No idea why, but IIS does allow it. In fact it's for this reason that you could identify the problem in IIS, as default documents would not render either if things were not configured correctly in Tomcat. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Jordan is correct, this is a connector issue with CF10/IIS.

This question is similar to:

[Coldfusion 10 on Windows 2k8 - .com/ loads OK but .com/index.cfm gives a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791113/coldfusion-10-on-windows-2k8-com-loads-ok-but-com-index-cfm-gives-a-404)

I posted an answer to that question that may be useful to others who find this question.

I had the same problem but the "Web Server Configuration Tool" (i.e. wsconfig) did not work for me.  My answer to this other question provides info on how to manually install the connector in IIS 7.x.