# Coldfusion 10 on Windows 2k8 - .com/ loads OK but .com/index.cfm gives a 404

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

I'm setting up a new server (CF10 W2K8) going by Pete Freitag's new CF10 lockdown guide.  I have a test site installed and if I bring up www.mydomain.com it loads the default document (index.cfm) just fine.  However, if I try www.mydomain.com/index.cfm (or any other specific .cfm page), I get a 404 not found.

IIS logs do record a 404 error.  If I create a .htm/.html page it comes up fine.

Comment: I had this problem too, just gave up and used Apache instead :-)

Comment: Sorry, just letting you know you're not the only one :-)

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved Steve?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.  Running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I found some threads that suggested that I re-run the "Web Server Configuration Tool" that is installed with CF 10 ({cfroot}\cfusion\runtime\bin\wsconfig.exe).

I tried several things including "Add..." using the name of the server (instead of localhost).  Then when I removed it (connections using the name of the server), I could see the IIS commands getting executed to remove all of the connection settings.  I also removed the localhost connection.  However, using "Add..." to attempt to add localhost back never worked.

So, for me, this tool only worked for removing the cfm/IIS settings that allowed CF to work.  My next step was going to be a reinstall of CF 10.  However, I found a link to this page:

http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion10-iis-manual-connector-configuration.html

I followed the instructions on that page with a few exceptions.  I didn't need to follow steps #1 & #2.  The file (isapi_redirect.dll) was still there.  Steps #3 - #5 were verified (the files existed and had the correct information in them).  Everything worked after I finished the steps, except document root documents (http://website.com/).  All I had to do was add index.cfm as a server-wide "Default Document".  Adobe forgot that step in their instructions.

I don't know why the "Web Server Configuration Tool" failed to install on my server.  I even tried running it "Run as administrator" with no success.

I did have to add the virtual directories (CFIDE & jakarta) to all the sites on the server as well.

You can use these handy command-line snippets to speed up that process if you have multiple sites to manage:

rem add cfide virtual directory (CF 10):

```
    %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add vdir /app.name:"site.com/" /path:/CFIDE /physicalPath:"{cfroot}\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE"
```

rem add jakarta virtual directory (CF 10):

```
    %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add vdir /app.name:"site.com/" /path:/jakarta /physicalPath:"{cfroot}\config\wsconfig\1"
```

Just replace the "site.com" and {cfroot} values to work with your server.

Comment: Update: Running {CF10 Install location}\cfusion\bin\connectors\Upgrade_all_connectors.bat updates the connectors.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up additional sites you must create a virtual directory called jakarta that is mapped to the /config/wsconfig/1 folder

Comment: I also setup one for cfide going to C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE but maybe that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - forgot to mark this closed.  I reformatted and reinstalled everything per the CF10 lockdown guide and it worked that time.

I know one problem I had was mapping a virtual 'jakarta' directory in IIS, but I never came up with a specific solution for the domain.com/index.cfm issue.