# cfm page will not be denied access

Tags: coldfusion

You want to achieve the access denied page, but in IIS8 of cfm can not prevent you from access to me. 
I have set so as not be able to access the user2 in authorization rules to the site. 
user2 will map the client certificate. 
I have disabled anonymous authentication. 
Although to get the error of 401.3 If you access the test.html 
in spite of have access denied to test.cfm 
It tends to be connected. 
I would like to reject the cfm page but How do I.

Comment: @user3835317, perhaps also include the original Japanese version of the question too? (Google translate says: @user3835317、私はあなたもあなたの質問のための日本語テキストが含まれていることを示唆している。)

Comment: Hi, I am the person who was talking to you on Twitter. I'm glad you got signed up for StackOverflow.  Are you trying to prevent .cfm files from running inside a specific folder-- such as an upload folder for security?

Comment: For example, I you have a cfm and html in directory A. 
I use the access denied to directory A. 
html page is access denied. (401.2) 
cfm page can be connected. 
Or from being able to connect to the cfm page why even though it has already been the access denied.

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, I think I'm starting to get a better picture. It sounds like you are trying to deny all access to file in a given directory.  You have attempted to do this in IIS by disabling anonymous access to that directory.  Your settings are successfully blocking access to HTML files, but users can still access the cfm file.  Is that correct?

Comment: There is a user B and user A. 
User B to deny access to the file. 
But I will be able to access the CFM page. 

Anonymous Authentication: Disabled 
Authorization rule: access denied (user B) 
Access Denied: User B 
Requires SSL: SSL configuration 
Client certificate: required 
I have mapped two certificates in the configuration editor 

Access to the CFM page is not correct.

Comment: What kind of security are you using?  How are users of your site authenticating? Is this IIS NTLM?  Basic HTTP Auth?  Client Certificate Mapping?  Can you provide more details about what you expect to happen and what is actually happening?  It is not clear from your comments.  And also, please add ALL these details to the original question. More details are better.

Comment: I have issued the client certificate. 
I am using the mapping. 
I want to deny approval user2 in the URL. 
There is no NTLM. 

It was only a matter of DirectoryC, but the situation has changed a little now.

Comment: Question changes, I'm sorry. 

401.2 error is obtained by DirectoryB that permission. 

What should I do in order for CFM page is displayed correctly.

Comment: Ok, so you're using authentication via a client certificate in IIS.  As for what you're trying to achieve and the unexpected result you are getting, I'm afraid I just don't understand.  I see the image you added, but I don't know what the X and O represents or if that image is showing what you WANT or what you are GETTING.  We may need to find a translator for this to work.

Comment: It is whether or not to allow access to that directory. 
For example userB can not access the directory A. 

It is difficult in the translation seems to still ...

Comment: I've found the cause. 
However, the problem does not solve. 
Jakarta virtual directory is a problem. 
Whether it is necessary to change the priority of the module?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are into IIS 8 and Coldfusion 10 looking for a login logout solution but the page errors, correct?

You may need to rerun the coldfusion config. See this similar post.

[Coldfusion 10 on Windows 2k8 - .com/ loads OK but .com/index.cfm gives a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791113/coldfusion-10-on-windows-2k8-com-loads-ok-but-com-index-cfm-gives-a-404)